# Django + Nginx save uploded file to other server and reverse file

Tags: django, nginx

I have 2 servers: first for Nginx and Django and second server for storage

```
Nginx and app server IP: 192.168.1.1

storage server IP: 192.168.1.2
```

Nginx installed on two servers.

In Django config media path:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Nginx config is in the first server:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name 192.168.1.1;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log ;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location  /media/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2/;
    }


    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:/tmp/uwsgi/app.sock;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /static/  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/app/static/;
    }

}
```

and storage server Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name 192.168.1.2;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log ;

    location /media/  {
      alias /home/ubuntu/app/media;
   }
}
```

**Questions:**

How can Django save (upload file) to the storage server (192.168.1.2)?

better if suggest solutions with minimum changes in code.

How Nginx can reverse files from a storage server?

the end user just typing 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: Network File System (NFS)**

An example of NFS is [GlusterFS](https://www.gluster.org/).

What it does is, it makes multiple disks or servers available as a single directory. So you can configure it to show your other server as media directory and any files you put in there, it will be automatically stored in your other server. And you can fetch those files as if they are in the media directory even though they are on another machine. No changes required to your django code, or nginx config.

**Solution 2: Custom File Storage backend**

Another solution is to write your own [File Storage backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/files/#file-storage) and save the images to your second server from there. In fact, there's a library called `django-storages` which supports uploading files to another server using FTP. See docs: http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/ftp.html

---

Personally, second solution seems better to me because you don't really need NFS right now. And even if you do later on, you can install Gluster on your second server and scale out from there.

Comment: thanks, for method 2, I have to use FTP to connect to another server?

Comment: server 1 have 2  network, first public and second private and connect to storege via private network.

Comment: @AmirAbdollahi You don't need to use FTP if you write your own Storage backend. And yeah, you can connect using both, private and public IP address, if your network configuration allows it.

Comment: Ok, can I  mount a folder as folder?
Can I use this solution? Is this a good solution?

Comment: @AmirAbdollahi Are you talking about the first solution using NFS? Yes it is good. But I think you should go with solution #2. That seems a more scalable approach to me.

Comment: No, I think, I can handle this problem simply. https://serverfault.com/questions/410588/how-to-mount-a-directory-from-another-server

Comment: If I can use mount folder as folder. I can solve solution with at least change and in the future if work grows up, I can use Gluster. Is this true?

Comment: @AmirAbdollahi Ah! That's a creative solution. Yes you can use Gluster later on if you need. Good luck.